# Output file writing array to the same line

Tags: c#, arrays, file-io

I'm currently trying to write a 2d int array to file. I've gotten it to write the data to file but it all appears on the same line.

Currently its appearing like this:

```
15101219816911171076171411881213567131441415101069101413878101181210156976139188711571210891267910
```

But I want it to appear like this:

```
15,10,12,19,8
16,9,11,17,10
7,6,17,14,11
8,8,12,13,5
6,7,13,14,4
1,4,15,10,10
6,9,10,14,13
8,7,9,10,11
8,12,10,15,6
9,7,6,13,9
18,8,7,11,5
7,12,10,8,9
12,6,7,9,10
```

This is my code.

```
        {
            StreamWriter outputfile;

            File.WriteAllText("ClosingStock.Txt", string.Empty);
            outputfile = File.AppendText("ClosingStock.Txt");

            for (int i = 0; i < (StockColumns); i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < (StockRows); j++)
                {
                    outputfile.Write(Global_Stock[i , j]);
                }
            }
            outputfile.Close();
        }
       
        
    }

Any help with this problem would be much appreciated. Thanks.
```

Comment: Thanks everyone for your help. Got it to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
        {
            StreamWriter outputfile;
            string comma = "";

            File.WriteAllText("ClosingStock.Txt", string.Empty);
            outputfile = File.AppendText("ClosingStock.Txt");

            for (int i = 0; i < (StockColumns); i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < (StockRows); j++)
                {
                    outputfile.Write(comma);
                    outputfile.Write(Global_Stock[i , j]);
                    comma = ",";
                }
                comma = System.Environment.NewLine);
            }
            outputfile.Close();
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You should first create a string to write into a file and then write it at once

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

for (int i = 0; i < (StockColumns); i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < (StockRows); j++)
    {
        sb.Append(Global_Stock[i , j]);
        sb.Append(",")
    }
}

File.WriteAllText("ClosingStock.Txt",sb.ToString());
```

Comment: I tried that and got it to work. Sorry, I formatted the way I wanted it to appear incorrectly. How would I get it to appear with a new line after every 5th value?

Comment: Thanks for your help btw. Much appreciated.

Comment: @TheUnawarePenguin so you want to write to a new line after every 5th value?

Answer (score 1):

Just add a new line after each inner loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < (StockColumns); i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < (StockRows); j++)
    {
        outputfile.Write(Global_Stock[i , j]);
    }
    outputfile.Write(Environment.NewLine);
}
```

If I had to guess you should switch `StockColumns` with `StockRows` in your loops to have the output you want.
Also, see @Mihir Dave for better implementation of writing a string to a file.